# Reference reactive properties dynamically

Tags: vue.js

How can I change a reactive properties by referencing them dynamically?

If I have some reactive properties:

```
const page = ref('1');
const item = ref('1');
const product = ref('ok');
const note = ref(5);
```

Then there is a function that takes an object whis is supposed to update any of these properties. So I have an array with the names of the properties to match with the properties and the keys in the object.

```
const update = (object) = {

   const properties = ['page', 'item', 'product', 'note'];

   properties.forEach(prop => {

    if(prop in object){
    // update the component property matching the current object key by the object property value
        // ?   = object[prop]

    }
  }
}
    
const object = {
    note: 'new value for note'
}

update(object);
```

Or is this not possible?
I would also need it to work with typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap that reactive properties by  `reactive` function named `state` :

```js
const state = reactive({
    page: '1',
    item: '1',
    product: 'ok',
    note: 1,
})

const update = (object) => {
    const properties: Array<keyof typeof state> = ['page', 'item', 'product', 'note']

    properties.forEach((prop) => {
        if (prop in object) {
            state[prop] = object[prop]
        }
    })
}

const object: Partial<state> = {
    note: 'new value for note',
}

update(object)
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to remove `page`, etc refs, they could be wrapped like `const state = reactive({ page, ...` and still be used separately

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you but I don't understand your remark

Comment: There is no need to choose between refs and reactive state. It's possible to keep the refs as is if they are needed separately, and use a state only to make the updates possible, like `const page = ref('1'); ... const state = reactive({ page, item, ... })`

Comment: Yes you're right, or `toRefs` them